# Check existing file and return the name of file

Tags: c#, directory, filenames, file-exists

I have a folder: E:\Photo. I want to check is there any file ".CR2" in the folder. If it exists, return the name of file ".CR2" (For ex, return E:\Photo\0102.CR2). I just know how to check whether existing file ".CR2" by `File.Exist()`, but I don't know how to return the file name. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Return from what and to what? Without any code nobody can guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you´re looking for:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Photo\*.CR2");
```

This will get *all* files with the extension `CR2`. If you need just the first use `files.First()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is totally what I want!

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = GetFileNames("D:\\Documents","docx");
    }
    public static string[] GetFileNames(string dirPath,string extention)
    {
        string[] files = { };
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*." + extention).Length > 0)
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*." + extention);
            List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                tempList.Add(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, file.Length - file.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1));
            }
            files = tempList.ToArray();
        }
        return files;
    }
```

This method returns an array of string with all the files. You can pass the directory name and name of extention to the  method.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private String GetFiles(string PathFolderName)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(PathFolderName);

            foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
            {
               if (fi.ToString().Contains(".CR2"))
               {
                   return fi.ToString();
               }

            }
            return string.Empty;

        }
```

to use:

```
string resultfile =  GetFiles("E:\\FilesFoldername");
```